# ASP.NET MVC ajax call does not work first time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a simple controller action that is being called from javascript in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0. The call does not work on the first attempt (action method not called) but does on the second. It looks as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Simpler(string model)
{
    return View();
}

$("#simple-submit").on('click', function () {

      alert('I am called');

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/Search/Simpler",
          data: "model=myval",
          success: function (result) {},
          error: function (error) {}
      });
});
```

The alert pops up both first and second time.
If I change the data to null, like:

```
     data: null,
```

The call goes through even on the first time.
If I check loaded js scripts they are there (like jquery).
Clearing the browser cache does not seem to affect.
I also tried the json notation like:

```
data: { "model": "myval" },
```

with the same results.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "The call does not work on the first attempt (action method not called)" ? Do you get a 404 error ?

Comment: What I mean is I put a breakpoint in the action method in the controller and the break point is not hit the first time. In the next attempt it is. I checked in Network in F12 and the method call is shown as: "(pending)". Except for that I only get 200 and 304 responses.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the network tab (F12) please ? to see the state of the requests.

Comment: What happens if you call the /Search/Simpler` URL directly from your browser ? Do you get a 404 ? If so, what if you remove the `httpPost` attribute ? Is your breakpoint hit ?

Comment: I do get a 404 when calling directly from the browser. If I remove the [HttpPost] it works directly from the browser and using my application it works even the first time then. Why would POST not work the first time? The method is not supposed to be idempotent so it should not be a GET.

Comment: This is honestly quite weird but without any more info, i can't help. Do you have any way to share the whole project or does it contain sensitive data ? If you want me to i could run it on my PC and see if i can reproduce the error. Without a local instance i can't really help you debug more :-/